# SharePoint 2010 Ribbon control

Tags: sharepoint

In SharePoint 2010, the default current view dropdown box(Library Tools-->Library-->All Documents) doesn't display items in an alphatical order. So if we want to disply the items in alphatical order, i think we have the following two options.

Option 1: Customizing the ribbon control 
Option 2: writing javascript file to sort the dropdown item lists and intergrating with ribbon control

Is there any other better option?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the View doesn't help? In SPS 3.0, in the Document Library, you can click view in the upper right corner, then edit the options in there. By default, ours sorts the Library based on the name of the file